# Java RMI - Is registry.bind blocking and how can server know if Client is down

Tags: java, rmi, rpc

I have 2 separate questions about Java RMI in a simple hello-world client-server application using RMI at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

(1) In the Server code, is the registry.bind("Hello", stub); a blocking-call ?
I want to eventually make my program peer-to-peer so I would need my server to continue after exporting an interface. Is there a way to continue execution in my server main after I export my interface ?

(2) In my remote method executing on the server I return a String. Suppose my client crashes while just before the remote method on server wants to return. Can I detect this in my server remote method. Specifically can this work in the remote method -

```
..
try {
return str;
} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.err.println("Client seems to be down so cannot return"); return str; 
}
```

The above is roughly what I want to achieve and the exception does not seem to be triggered:
(a) Do I need to throw a particular type of exception ? http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/rmi/spec/rmi-exceptions.doc.html
(b) If this will even work, I still need to return something in the catch {} block to not get a compilation error. That seems logically incorrect.

I can do the reverse i.e - In client I receive an exception is the Server crashes so my remote method cannot return, but here I need to detect in the server if the client has died before the remote method in server returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) In the Server code, is the registry.bind("Hello", stub); a blocking-call ? I want to eventually make my program peer-to-peer so I would need my server to continue after exporting an interface. Is there a way to continue execution in my server main after I export my interface ?

It is blocking for the duration of the call, but all the call has to do essentially is HashMap.add() with a bit of error checking. It doesn't prevent continued execution of the code after it while something external happens, in the sense that accept() does.

> (2) In my remote method executing on the server I return a String. Suppose my client crashes while just before the remote method on server wants to return. Can I detect this in my server remote method. Specifically can this work in the remote method

No. The RMI framework may detect and handle the case after your return statement has executed, but you won't be told about it. It will log the problem and close the connection.

> I need to detect in the server if the client has died before the remote method in server returns.

You can't. The only way provided by RMI to know about disappearing clients is the Unreferenced interface.

Comment: Thanks, but if possible could you help me understand in some more detail ? 

(1) What is blocking "for the duration of the call" - in the hello-world example the server seems to be blocking indefinitely (a System.out.println didnt get executed after it). I've currently put the export and bind calls in a thread separate from the main(), but would still like to know how to continue execution after those calls. Why Hashmap.Add() will do so and where do I need to put this - not getting the concept.

Comment: (2) It seems implementing unreferenced will invoke a method when the number of clients holding a reference to my remote method becomes 0. Then I can check on the server as to how many clients are down from the full list. Is this the idea ? If so why isn't this triggered initially before any clients have tried connecting to the remote method ? It's not working for me now when I kill the client while the server method is executing either so some examples might help. http://www.coderanch.com/t/183723/java-developer-SCJD/certification/Implementin-Unreferenced

Comment: @PKM If the print method did not execute after `bind` then something is wrong. It could be a connection issue that never times-out. As EJP said, the code execution might halt a bit during the method call, but not after it completes.

Comment: @PKM (1) It means that like any other call, execution only continues when it returns, but it returns more or less immediately unless there  is a connection timeout, which takes about a minute, or an exception you haven't told us about. (2) You don't have to put HashMap.add() anywhere. That's what the Registry does when you call bind(). (3) Unreferenced tells you when the number of clients *of the remote object* has just become zero, from being > 0. At that point you should just clear the list of clients. It takes a while to trigger as it relies on the DGC mechanism.

Comment: @PKM The client hold references to a remote object, not to a remote method. When `unreferenced` is called probably all the clients are down.

Comment: @PKM It is in the nature of TCP that the condition you describe cannot be detected until afterwards.